# Minimization over Booles

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I would like to set my domain of `NMinimize` so that my variables take values in `{1,0}`. I know I can use `Booleans` in `FindInstance`, but how can I define this in `NMinimize` to avoid writing it in the conditions? Here's the shape of my code

```
n=10;v={1,2,3,4,1,5,1,4,6,1};
xi = Array[x, n];
NMinimize[{Total[v xi],
    AllTrue[xi, (# == 0 || # == 1) &]
  }, xi]
```

This is a strange example. My `v` and `n` will be bigger and I have more conditions, so I'm looking for ways of optimising the minimisation.

Comment: `NMinimize[{Total[v xi], And @@ Thread[0 <= xi <= 1]}, xi, Integers]`?

Comment: Would that be faster than my code?

Comment: I get an error "Options expected (instead of $\mathbb{Z}$ beyond position 2 in (...)"

Comment: sorry, meant `Minimize[...]` (not `NMinimize[...]`).  Not sure if it is faster.

Comment: It seems way faster! I'll try it for a more complicated case

Comment: The method proposed by @kglr should be much faster for large `n`. The `Or`'d constraints are likely to spawn 2^n separate subproblems. The `And`'d inequalities can be as bad, in theory, but in practice a branch-and-bound ILP solver will do better than worst-case (sometimes much better).